# Now getting from RubyMotion uninitialized constant MotionModel::SQLite3Adapter after setting detect_dependencies = false

Tags: rubymotion, motionmodel

I have been adding the sqlite3 as the persistent storage and it seems t work property, however I get: 
WARNING: Automatic dependency detection does not work with motion-support. Turn it off in your Rakefile:

app.detect_dependencies = false

I do this and the app no longer compiles, it gives the 'uninitialized constant MotionModel::SQLite3Adapter' error. Comment out the line and it works with the message.

My rake file is:

```
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib"
require 'motion/project/template/ios'

require 'rubygems'
#require 'motion/project'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

$: << File.expand_path('../../lib', __FILE__)
require 'motion_model'
require 'motion_model/sql'
require 'motion_model/fmdb'


Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  app.name = 'VrWizard'
  app.frameworks += [ "CoreText"]
  app.detect_dependencies = false
  app.vendor_project('vendor/MYCalendar', :static)
  app.pods do
    pod 'NanoStore', '~> 2.6.4'
  end
end
```

And my my gem file contains:

```
gem 'motion_model',  :git => 'https://github.com/sxross/MotionModel.git', :branch => 'sql'
```

I attempted to use the master MotionModel, however there is no sql in it.

I just don't want something to come up and bite me later.  From what I read the flag was added while the auto dependency was experimental in 1.26.  Is this a remanent warming that should be removed?  If I need it, how do I solve the new error?

Don French

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the SQL Adapter for MotionModel. You can safely ignore the warning with respect to MotionModel. Dependency detection is required for MotionModel, but the author of motion-support felt his gem was not.

Comment: I was hoping that was the case. I have been doing heavy testing and have had no issue. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly discourage disabling the detect_dependencies feature. Nearly all RubyMotion gems are written to take advantage of it. It's probably safe to ignore the warning.